# time series analysis Rcpp, RInside

Tags: c++, r

I want to call `R` time series analysis functions from `C++`.
Does anybody have working example for the same.

Comment: I imagine there's something relevant in the 8 vignettes provided for Rcpp: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html

Comment: RInside ships with over a dozen examples, and two in particular are pretty close.